# How i can create boot partition for ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

i had a dual boot win/ubuntu both OS are on separate ssd

and i had to replace my laptop so i took an image for the boot partition on the ssd where windows is located then i have format the entire sdd

and i kept ubuntu on the other ssd as its, but now after i attached that ssd to the new laptop, ubuntu boot was not detected

so i have used the image of the boot partition and restore it on empty space for ubuntu ssd, and i have managed to get it work, problem that now i have in grup menu 3 boots.

1 ubuntu
1 windows from the old ssd
1 windows from the current laptop

so how i can remove the unused boot for old windows and replace it with the actual working win boot

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo update-grub` form Ubuntu? That should add your working Windows to your grub menu and remove the redundant ones.

Comment: great, now i have the new working boot but the non working one is still listed how i can remove it

Comment: Can you edit your question showing the non working menuentry from grub.cfg? is it under ` /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ` in grub.cfg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download "Grub Customizer"

```
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

Open it and you can delete the unnecessary boot option from there.

Comment: yes this helped me, i have removed the extra boot in grub menu but im still able to see one extra boot (old windows) on the boot settings.

is there way to remove it as well

Comment: @amrkdev Possibly. You will have to do it from boot settings. However, how you have to do it depends on your motherboard. Look for "Remove boot option" in boot settings.